# How to check an ascending ordered column value in where clause in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, where-clause

I am new to postgresql. I want to join two tables if one geometry of first table is contained by the geometry of second table. So, I have written and executed this part of the query as following and it is running fine.

```
select edge.start_id, cls.gid 
from edge_table edge 
   inner join cluster_info cls on st_contains(cls.geom,st_setsrid(edge.start_geom,3067));
```

But it is giving the start_id and its containing geom id (as mentioned cls.gid in the query) in a random order such as following:

```
start_id gid
26040   2493
43323   2490
26208   2400
42754   2433
43537   2434
1379    2434
43570   2904
42887   2475
43689   2495
43211   2904
```

But I need to insert the result in another column named start_cls in my edge table. I need to identify the row where the cls.gid should be inserted. So, I need to check the value of start_id for each row and the cls.gid corresponding to that start_id should be put in that row. Assume, four rows of my edge table are following:

```
gid start_id    end_id  start_geom                                  end_geom                                    start_cls     end_cls
1   81608       81608   01010000007368912D8B622341E5D022EBEAF65A41  01010000007368912D8B622341E5D022EBEAF65A41                  
2   81557       81520   010100000085EB51F89C0723418B6CE7DB9F8E5A41  0101000000986E1203DE0723416DE7FB51A38E5A41                  
3   189898      80812   01010000006F1283C0A093214179E926F1A1005B41  0101000000BE9F1A6FF3942141022B871EEC005B41                  
4   80952       80476   0101000000666666E67F832341F2D24DBA38B45A41  0101000000736891EDB48423413BDF4F755AB45A41
```

I need to fill the start_cls column first.  So, the cls.gid value of 81608 (first start_id) should be there at first row under start_cls column. So, I have given one where clause as following:

```
select edge.start_id, cls.gid 
from edge_table edge 
  inner join cluster_info cls on st_contains(cls.geom,st_setsrid(edge.start_geom,3067))
where (select start_id from edge_table) = edge.start_id;
```

But, it is giving following error:

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
********** Error **********

ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
SQL state: 21000
```

I tried with the following query too but no luck.

```
select edge.start_id, cls.gid 
from edge_table edge 
   inner join cluster_info cls on st_contains(cls.geom,st_setsrid(edge.start_geom,3067))

where (select start 
       from (select start_id as start 
             from edge_table) as s) = edge.start_id;
```

Please help with this query. It has some geometry part but the main problem is in postgresql query organisation. So, I have raised this question in stackoverflow instead of gis.stackexchange.

Comment: `select start_id from edge_table` retruns more then one row... what did you want to achieve by `where (select start_id from edge_table) = edge.start_id;`?

Comment: I want to get the start ids of each row one by one

Comment: do you have several `cluster_info.start_cls ` for each `edge.start_id`?.. update question with both tables sample data

Comment: No, for each start_id, I have one start_cls

Comment: `select edge.*, cls.start_cls, cls.end_cls
from edge_table edge 
   inner join cluster_info cls on st_contains(cls.geom,st_setsrid(edge.start_geom,3067));` ?..

Comment: Then? It will do the same what I have done. How do I identify the row where to put the cls.gid value? And cluster_info table does not contain start_cls and end_cls. I am finding it by checking the contents og cls.geom.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134680/discussion-between-vao-tsun-and-lsg).